# Angular 12 - formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive error

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 12 and I'm getting the error in console. I am using the form inside the modal. Where am I missing?

**profile.component.ts**

```
updateForm!: FormGroup;
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.username = this.router.snapshot.params['username']
    this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.username = params['username'];
      this.getOne(); // reset and set based on new parameter this time
  });
}

  getOne(){
    this.dataService.getProfile(this.username).pipe(
      map(resp => [resp])
     ).subscribe(res=>{(
       this.playerData = res,
       this.userProfiles = this.playerData[0])
       this.updateForm= new FormGroup({
         name:  new FormControl(this.userProfiles?.name),
         user_info: new FormControl(this.userProfiles?.user_info)
       });
     })
  }
```

**profile.html**

```
<form class="comment-form"  [formGroup]="updateForm" id="editProfileForm" >

     <div class="row"> 
         <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
     </div>
               
     <textarea formControlName="user_info" rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>

     <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-info" (click)="updateProfile()" >Save</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your update form isn't populated by the time Angular tries to render the component template. You need to add an `*ngIf` to your template as such:

```
<form *ngIf="updateForm" class="comment-form" [formGroup]="updateForm" id="editProfileForm">
```

Comment: not working. still getting same error

Comment: You'll need  the `*ngIf` statement on the form regardless due to the async call to get the profile data. I would ensure you're getting a formGroup instance when your `getProfile()` call emits a value.

Comment: so what should I do exactly? actually I don't understand

Comment: Ensure that your methods are returning what you expect. For example, when you subscribe to `getProfile()` is it making it into the body of the function to initialize the form group?

Answer (score 0):

Make one correction in defining formgroup in your code-
updateForm: FormGroup;

Also try with this below approach-

```
 <div class="row"> 
     <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control">
 </div>
           
 <textarea formControlName="user_info" rows="8" class="form-control"></textarea>

 <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-info" (click)="updateProfile()" >Save</button>
```